# code analysis warning CA2000 which should not occur

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I have a small issue with a CA2000 warning. In my project which is set as startup project, I get this warning, although it should not occur.

Background: I am using Visual Studio 2010 with projects in .NET 3.5. The startup project is a WPF application.

In the class App looks as follows:

```
public partial class App : System.Windows.Application {

        /// <summary>
        /// Application Entry Point.
        /// </summary>
        [System.STAThreadAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public static void Main() {
            AutoTester.App app = new AutoTester.App();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

The warning says:

Warning 1   CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'App.Main()', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'app' before all references to it are out of scope.  C:\Projects\Freelance\svn\AutoTester\Application\Applications\AutoTester\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs 47  AutoTester

As one can see, the warning occurs in the App.g.cs which is an auto-generated file. In the project properties I have deactivated code analysis for autogenerated files. "Supress results from auto-generated code". Therefore, this warning should not occur, right?

Now my problem is, that I cannot locally suppress the warning because the code will be overriden. Also, I do not want to make a rule for that globally, because I don't want to deactivate CA2000.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or any idea what is going wrong here?

Best wishes,
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Supress results from auto-generated code" indicates that results from code that is auto-generated is not shown. Visual Studio knows that code is generated by a third-party only if it contains the `GeneratedCodeAttribute` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.generatedcodeattribute.aspx)). Apprarently, the tool that created your code didn't add the attribute.

You can try to make another partial class of App and put the attribute there:

```
[GeneratedCode("CodeGenerator", "1.0.0.0")]
public partial class App 
{
}
```

Comment: Ahh that sounds interesting. However that is still strange since this file was created by the VisualStudio. It's what happens when you create a new Project (WPF Application). I think Microsoft should use the GeneratedCodeAttribute. I will try to create another WPF project and see what happens.

Comment: Okay I found the problem: If you create a WPF application using .NET 4.0 it adds the generated code attribute. However, if you create a WPF application in .NET 3.5 it does not add that attribute. This is quite annoying but there is nothing I could do about it, right?

Your solution with creating another partial class worked, thank you!

Comment: Since a developer may well add functionality to the `App` class above (or another in the same namespace) might this attribute suppress valid warnings?